# Retrieve responsible user for channel delete in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a alert system where if someone deletes a channel it sends a message with the name of the channel that was deleted and the Deleter, so i tried making it by coding *this* :

```
client.on('channelDelete', channel => {
  var channelDeleteAuthor = channelDelete.action.author
  const lChannel = message.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'bot-logs')
  if (!channel) return; channel.send(`Channel Deleted by ${channelDeleteAuthor}`)
  .then(message => console.log(`Channel Deleted by ${channelDeleteAuthor}`))
  .catch(console.error)

})
```

and it didn't work, how do i achieve that action?

Comment: *what* variable is not defined?

Comment: *var channelDeleteAuthor = channelDelete.action.author*

Comment: i think you know what is the variable

Comment: Not really. It could have been `channelDelete` or `message`, since neither of them is defined in the code you're showing. So, how/where are they defined? Or at least where/how is `channelDelete` defined?

Comment: i am trying to find the way how i could mention the deleter

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that information is not provided by Discord in the channel deletion event. You would need to check the audit log if you want the user that deleted the channel. Also, like stated above `channelDelete` and `message` have not been defined.

Answer (score 3):

To find the author of the deletion, you need to parse the guild audit log.

```
client.on('channelDelete', channel => {
  // get the channel ID
  const channelDeleteId = channel.id;

  // finds all channel deletions in the log
  channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({'type': 'CHANNEL_DELETE'}) 
  // find the log entry for this specific channel
  .then( logs => logs.entries.find(entry => entry.target.id == channelDeleteId) ) 
  .then (entry => {
    // get the author of the deletion
    author = entry.executor;

    // do whatever you want
    console.log(`channel ${channel.name} deleted by ${author.tag}`);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

})
```